# Importance of estimating $\sigma^2$ in linear Statistical model

Tags: statistics, reference-request, normal-distribution

Statistical model for *Complete Randomized design*

$y_{ij} = \mu + \tau_i + \epsilon_{ij}$

where, $i$ denotes treatment and $j$ denotes observation.

$i=1,2,...,k\quad and \quad j=1,2,..., n_i$

$y_{ij}$ be a random variable that represents the response obtained on the $jth$
observation of the  $ith$ treatment.

$\mu$ is the overall mean of the response $y_{ij}$

$\tau_i$ is the effect on the response of $ith$ treatment.

$\mu_i = \mu + \tau_i$

here $\mu_i$ denotes the *true response*  of the $ith$ treatment.

and $\epsilon_{ij}$ is the random error term represent the sources of nuisance variation that is, variation due to factors other than treatments.

the assumption is $\epsilon_{ij}\sim^{iid} N(0,\sigma^2)$

By *Least Square Estimation Procedure* we estimate $\mu\quad and\quad\tau_i$.

- Why is it also important to estimate $\sigma^2$?
   If we do not estimate it , what will be the effect?

Any help including reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without estimating the error variance you cannot estimate the variability in your parameters and hence cannot conduct hypothesis tests.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question. We know, $E(MSE)=\sigma^2$. Could you tell me how can we write $\hat\sigma^2=MSE$?

Comment: Does Variability in parameters denote the variability among $\tau_i$'s ?